# ROS2 - a problem with tf frame in Rivz

Tags: ros2, rviz, tf

i'm simulating auto docking algorithm using Apritag in ROS2, when robot detect apriltag the apriltag tf frame appear in tf rviz but after robot not detect apriltag, apriltag tf in rivz is still appear, it is'nt lost tf as in ROS1. Anyone help me!

[image]

[image]